# Opening a SharePoint file or folder in a browser, by its GUID

Tags: rest, url, guid

In my app, outside of SharePoint, I want to construct a URL to take me straight to a SharePoint file or folder in a browser. My app's database has a table containing the unique IDs (GUIDs) of some SP files and folders that have been created programmatically - I store each GUID at the time of creation so that if a user moves or renames something in SP in the future, I still have a way to reach it.

How best then to open a browser tab giving a view of a SP file or folder when I have its GUID? I know I can do it in two hops - I can call the REST GetFileById or GetFolderById API to get the ServerRelativeURL and then programmatically build a URL around the ServerRelativeURL. What I'd really like to do though is just to construct a URL containing the GUID. Is that possible?

Just to be clear, I mean unique ID as in "99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999", not the 1-based counter that shows an item's position in its container.

TIA,

Nick

Comment: Are you using "Document ID" feature or just a file GUID? In case of GUID, check this and let me know if it works: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/278894/construct-external-link-to-sharepoint-document-by-guid

Comment: Also, check if you can benefit using the "Document ID" feature to identify the files using document ID: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I'm using the UniqueID property. The StackExchange link you provided looks like it would work for Word docs and spreadsheets but I wanted something that will work for all document types, including non-MS documents like PDFs. I've coded something now where I retrieve the ServerRelativeURL for the uniqueID and open that URL in a browser. It is working fine for me, so I'll just go with that.